# Nivo Slider add logo over the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, nivo-slider

Hey guys I have setup Nivo slider to my specification, but what I want to be able to do is overlay my logo over the top of it. I have tried playing around with the z-index but to no avail.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Nivo Slider Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/pascal/pascal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/orman/orman.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header"><div class="slider-wrapper theme-default"><div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/dog.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="" />
          </div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css I've added

```
#header{
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;}

#content{
    width:900px;
    background:#0C6;
    color:#cccccc;
    margin-top:-120px;
    float:left;
    z-index:1000;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance
Adam

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us your source code?

Comment: updated my post, did a little js fiddler test and it was working, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/zdvPv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loaded it up on js fiddler and it seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/zdvPv/1/

---

As @Reporter said, its hard to know what your doing without any source. I just had a play with firbug and i was able to get something to sit over the nivoslider.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 300; left:500; height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red; z-index: 100;">hello</div>
```

this was placed outside of the slider div.  The code is terrible but its just a start for you to see if it would work, you could replace the div with an image or maybe have the image as a background of the div.

Edit: i messed around with firebug on this page: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ cant show you an image mind

Edit 2: My solution is HTML & CSS not really javascript, so not sure how you want this implemented.  You could dynamically inject the "overlay" using jquery

Comment: Right got the box displaying over the top but I have the slider margin 0 auto with a width of 900px; how do i get the red square to display margin 0 auto with a width of 900px, I've uploaded it to my webspace to play around with http://adamhuxtable.com/nivo/index.html

Thanks Rob for your help :)

Comment: becuase it is position absolute it is out of the flow of the document, so margin 0 auto wont work, you need to set with width and height of the slider and position it using the top and left properties over the top.  update the fiddler to show this http://jsfiddle.net/zdvPv/2/ used RGBA so use something like firefox to view

Comment: Ignore the above, just looked at your page, just move the overlay div into the #slider div and it will work itself out.

Comment: That seems to work but the only issue is everything inside the #slider is assumed to be included as part of the carousel. So the .overlay is on a slide of its own...

Comment: you could simply wrap the whole lot in another div, give it an id of slider-wrap, give that the margin auto and put everything in it, making sure that the slider-wrap css has position: relative

Comment: Thanks so much for your help got it working just the way I wanted it to :)